# Disconnect TFS Clone from production systems

Tags: upgrade, production-environment, test-environments

How can I ensure that a TFS 2010/2012 clone doesn't interact systems from my production environment? I want to run the clone in parallel for doing an upgrade test and some further tests. The clone should not interact with production systems. Is there a way to do that, without knowing all involved systems excatly?

Comment: Change Alert Handlers, Team Build Definitions (drop locations, symbol servers, deployment). Any more?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run the `ChangeServerId` command to ensure that the GUIDs for the configuration database and collection databases are changed. Here is a link to the MSDN article on the command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee349259.aspx

NOTE: You must ensure that the app tier is not configured for the databases before running this command. If an app tier is configured, you will need to run the `RemapDBs` command located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee349262.aspx and restart the `TfsJobAgent` service on the app tier.